# register ajax calls hook

Tags: ajax

I'm using ajax in a plugin for a front-end form.
But it only works if I place the `add_action("wp_ajax_..."` in the plugin loader. 
I would like to register the call in another file.

I have tried:

```
function my_plugin_init() {

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {

        require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/my-plugin-functions.php' );

    }

}
//add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_plugin_init' );
add_action( 'init', 'my_plugin_init' );
```

But neither `add_action` hook seems to work.  Ajax fails because it cannot find the ajax function in `inc/my-plugin-functions.php`.

If I place the ajax function in the plugin loader, everything works as expected:

```
function my_plugin_etc() {

    $title = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['title'] );

    $meta = update_post_meta(1234, 'test_key', $title);

    if ( $meta != false ) 
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Title added as postmeta.') );
    else 
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'There was a problem.' ) );

    wp_die();    

}
add_action("wp_ajax_my_plugin_etc", "my_plugin_etc");
```

I'd rather not put the ajax function in the plugin loader.

What is the proper hook to use to include a file so that the ajax function in that file is registered?

Comment: Is the function `my_plugint_init()` a typo?

Comment: Yes, just an exaple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Any* action that fires before the AJAX call is made will work. Generally speaking, `init` is good choice.

You mention that the ajax call is made from a "front-end form".  If that form is available to end-users who are **not** logged in, then you need to use:

```
add_action ('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_plugin_etc', 'my_plugin_etc') ;
```

See [wp_ajax_nopriv_{$_REQUEST[‘action’]}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv__requestaction/).

**Edit**

Must be my lack of sleep, because I should have seen this earlier.

`is_admin()` returns `false` during an invocation of `admin-ajax.php`.  Thus, change your `my_plugin_init()` to be:

```
function my_plugin_init() {

    if ( ! is_admin() || wp_doing_ajax ()) {

        require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/my-plugin-functions.php' );

    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'my_plugin_init' );
```

[wp_doing_ajax()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_doing_ajax/) was introduced in WP 4.7.

If your plugin needs to work in version of WP before that, then change it to:

```
function my_plugin_init() {

    if ( ! is_admin() || (defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX)) {

        require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/my-plugin-functions.php' );

    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'my_plugin_init' );
```

The advantage of `wp_doing_ajax()` over the pre-4.7 test (if you can get away with only supporting 4.7+) is that applies the  [wp_doing_ajax](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_doing_ajax/) filter to the value of `defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX` which can give you finer control over whether you want to consider yourself within an ajax context.  However, this extra control is probably not necessary in your case.

Finally, if `inc/my-plugin-functions.php` **only** contains code related to AJAX, then you remove `! is_admin() ||` from the `if` condition.

Comment: Only logged in users can access the form, but thanks.  So if I'm using init as a hook, any thoughts on why the ajax add_action only works in the plugin loader and not in a required file?

Comment: @shanebp see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you enqueued your script and then added wp_localize_script in the file you wish to use ajax?

```
// your javascript with ajax calls must be enqueued before wp_localize_script.     
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( 'file_location.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
            // Wordpress localize script
            wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
```